# Pandas - list of list not appended to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am parsing a list of items, item by item into pandas append function.
[pandas.DataFrame.append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import pandas as pd
import argparse
# from glob import glob


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=None)


def GetArgs(parser):
    """Parser function using argparse"""
    # parser.add_argument('directory', help='directory use',
    #                     action='store', nargs='*')
    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+")
    return parser.parse_args()

fileList = GetArgs(parser)
print(fileList.files)

data = []
frames = pd.DataFrame()

attrs = ('id', 'horse')

for items in fileList.files:
    d = pq(filename=items)
    res = d('nomination')
    dataSets = [[res.eq(i).attr(x)
                 for x in attrs] for i in range(len(res))]
    print(dataSets)
    aDF = pd.DataFrame(dataSets,)
    frames.append(aDF)


print(frames)
```

I can see from the output that I get the data and that, I am parsing a list of lists into the dfame to be appended however it is run an empty dataframe

```
(pyquery)sayth@sayth-E6410:~/Projects/pyquery$ python jqxml.py samples/*.xml
['samples/20160402RAND0.xml']
[['198247', 'Astern'], ['199039', 'El Divino'], ['199616', 'Geneteau'], ['197890', 'Alliterate'], ['201416', 'Hostwin Legend'], ['202829', 'Lionhearted'], ['199619', 'Mooshakissa'], ['202345', "Let's Dream Big"], ['200794', 'Prince Chabal'], ['202766', 'Red Handle'], ['198442', "He's Our Rokkii (NZ)"], ['188683', 'Odyssey Moon'],
...
['193862', 'Karaka Lass'], ['193850', 'Alittle Loose'], ['191829', "Aurora's Star"], ['196396', 'Shanakee (NZ)'], ['192985', 'Rainbow Park (NZ)'], ['192983', "Daisy's Joy"], ['198039', 'Shotgun Roulette'], ['188872', "Peggy's Cove"], ['188981', 'Heartlings']]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Unsure why this is not appending.

Comment: Can you make this a runnable example? IOW, scrape out all of the `getArgs` and file I/O related code and instead just hard-code some representative data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `append` is not an inplace function in pandas; it returns the appended result.  So, you need to redefine `frames` as the appended result:

```
frames = frames.append(aDF)
```